# Can I get a reference to my web request object from a WebException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using a `WebRequest` to send a POST request to a REST api to obtain some data. To assist with this, I am handling `WebException` exceptions on a **global** level, using a global filter, and (attempting to) log the url, params, and headers of both the request and response. Once I have my `WebException` object, I can easily get my response data and log it like so:

```
public class HandleMyErrorAttribute : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Exception raisedException = context.Exception;
        if (raisedException is WebException)
        {
            WebException wex = (WebException)raisedException;
            LogHelper.LogResponse(wex.Response);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I also need to be able to log all the request data as well. **Is there any way to get a reference to the request object from a `WebException`?** My goal is to have something along these lines:

```
public class HandleMyErrorAttribute : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Exception raisedException = context.Exception;
        if (raisedException is WebException)
        {
            WebException wex = (WebException)raisedException;
            LogHelper.LogResponse(wex.Response);
            LogHelper.LogRequest(wex.RequestObject);
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, there is no `Request` object in that excetion object (that I can see). Is there something I am missing? Is this even possible? Am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Thanks

Comment: To get access to the requested data you need to catch the exception in a more localized manner. The downside of the global exeception is exactly this, no specfic data.

Comment: Probably a dumb question... but is there anything in `context.RequestContext`?

Comment: Thanks @Poosh. And yes there is. But `context.RequestContext` contains info for the request that was sent to my controller. I'm looking for the object that contains info for the request that I am sending from my controller (to a remote host somewhere) that is generating the exception.